# 403 error while making Amazon SP API calls despite having LWA access and refresh tokens

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have followed the official developer's guide (https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs) to the teeth, and have been able to get access and refresh tokens. I have also managed to sign each request properly using SHA256 hashing algorithm. But after trying to make an API call, this is the error I get.

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
     "code": "Unauthorized",
     "details": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

The inline policy attached to the IAM Role is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::310069193681:role/SellingPartner"
        }
    ]
}
```

Attached below are other request details....

```json
{
  'Date': 'Mon, 12 Jul 2021 10:23:12 GMT', 
   'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  'Content-Length': '141', 
  'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
  'x-amzn-RequestId': '8541dac4-e734-486b-820d-3010f447b055', 
  'x-amzn-ErrorType': 'AccessDeniedException', 
  'x-amz-apigw-id': 'CWiykGXFDoEF2Xw='
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, for me I didn't give the roles needed for the app.

For your application to access a given resource you have to select some roles. To to this, if you are using the new interface:

1. Go to the page where your apps are listed
2. Select your app -> Edit
3. Select the roles you need. You can check which roles are necessary in

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/en-US/roles/Roles-in-the-Selling-Partner-API.md
Some roles are restricted - if that's your case, you might need to update your developer profile to request them.